# Show view hidden with TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I have a XML layout with 3 views: A, B, C ...  the view B is match_parent, and the view C isn't in screen, because view B fill all space.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/824/q2lw.png

In code, I start an animation in entire layout XML, the animation translate de parent view to the left, hiding the view A and showing the view C

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/41/0e1g.png

My problem, when I start the animation, the parent view goes to the left, hide the view A, but I don't know why, doesn't show the view C

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/823/hxht.png

I thought that view C was squeezed so I tried setLayoutParam in parent View and in View C when the animation end, but didn't work.

What I do?

Comment: did you specify android:layout_alignRight to view c ?? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignRight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use a HorizontalScrollView as parent of views A,B and C, this way I could move views.